# SQL View displaying incorrect data while the same sql code run in a query window gives correct data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

One of my SQL view when opened and run in a design window gives incorrect data while the same underlying SQL code is run in a new Query window gives correct data.  To be more specific, this view is pointing to a table where data changes on a daily basis.   Why am I getting stale data in the design view while the same (same view underlying sql) code run in a Query Window gives current data.  This has never happened before.  There is a excel sheet that connects to this view to pull data into reports and this is getting the stale data into the report.

What should I be looking at to fix this issue.

And the server is SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dima, No, I am not using Select *

Comment: SELECT     Number, Uni, AccountNum, Year, EndDate, StartBal, Debits, Credits, Net, EndBal, Name, Owner, PID
FROM         Activity
WHERE     (Number = 'AWAXZ') AND (Year = 2014) AND (AccountNum = '5110')

Comment: ok, then what kind of incorrect data you're getting?

Comment: Dima, I did the refresh this morning and also just now.  Still its the same

Comment: share your tables (schema) and the view in your question

Comment: This one AccountNum 5110 gets different debit and Net amounts in the design view while the copy pasting of the same underlying SQL into a query window gives correct amounts for Debit and Net

Comment: It is little more complicated as the view (Activity) itself looks at two other views and then indirectly linked to the underlying table.  Actually I am not even querying the table name.  I am querying the same view (Activity) in a new query window Verses in the design view of this view which gives me different results for this AccountNum

Answer (score 3):

You probably use `*` in your view to select all columns from some table

```
select * from table
```

when you add a new column to that table you'll need to re-run the view, then it'll work... `select *`, especially in view is generally considered a bad practice. In the case of a `*` metadata is not automatically updated when the tables (or schema for that matter) used in view are modified, therefore you'll need to `alter` the view

another way of refreshing it is running system stored proc:

```
EXEC sp_RefreshView vw_ViewName
```

Comment: Ran the sp_RefreshView on all the underlying views as well and this fixed the issue.  It's strange but worked.  Thanks for making me think in these lines...

Comment: glad it helped... for the future I recommend avoiding `select *` in the views. I've had this problem a few months ago and I was scratching my head off to figure it out...